# Assume $\theta_1-\theta_2=2n\pi$. Prove that $\text{Re}(z_1 \bar z_2)=|z_1||z_2|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I proved the other way around already but I can't seem to prove this way.  Both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the arguments of $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively.  Can anyone help me out here?

**Edit:**
The change I made was that $\bar z_2$ is the conjugate of $z_2$

Comment: This is false. Let $z_1=z_2=1+i$. Then $z_1z_2=(1+i)^2=2i$, so the real part is $0$, but the product of the magnitudes is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_{\small 1} = r_{\small 1}  e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_{\small 2}  = r_{\small 2}  e^{i\theta_2}$.

Then, $$z_{\small 1}\bar z_{\small 2} = r_{\small 1}r_{\small 2} e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)} = r_1r_2[\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)] $$

So, $$\text{Re}(z_{\small 1}\bar z_{\small 2})=r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=r_1r_2\cos(2n\pi)=r_1r_2=|z_1||z_2|$$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality assume that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both unequal to zero:

$\mathrm {Re}(z_1\bar z_1) =\mathrm {Re}(|z_1|e^{i\theta_1}|z_2|e^{-i\theta_2}) = |z_1||z_2|\mathrm {Re}(e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}) = |z_1||z_2|\mathrm {cos}(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

this is equal to $|z_1||z_2|$ iff $\mathrm {cos}(\theta_1-\theta_2)=1$ which is true iff $(\theta_1-\theta_2)/2\pi \in \mathbb{Z}$.